# How can I delete old Windows 7 directory

Tags: windows-7

Yesterday I've completed my first install Windows 7. I had to repeat installation because first time the pc hang up.

Now I got a Windows.old under c:\, and I'm unable to remove it.

When I try, I got an error saying I need authorization from Mint\parroit account, where Mint is my pc name and parroit is my own account, which I use to login.

How can I remove the folder? I also tryed to run the "Clean pc" util, but the folder it's still there.

If I run this command from command line:

```
del /s /f /q c:\Windows.old\*.*
```

I  got several access denied error.

I also tryed the solution suggested here: [Windows Vista Windows.Old Folder - Is it needed](https://superuser.com/questions/53628/windows-vista-windows-old-folder-is-it-needed)

but in Windows 7 there is no "Previous Windows installation(s) check box".

Comment: What method are you using to delete? Does it present you with a UAC dialog? Are you doing this from an admin account using an elevated instance of file explorer / cmd?

Comment: I'm just deleting from Windows Explorer. Yes, it present a UAC asking for administrator permission (which I confirm). parroit is an admin account, but I'm not using an elevated instance of file explorer... How can I do this?

Comment: If it's giving you the UAC prompt, then it shouldn't matter if the file explorer instance is elevated or not (but if you wish to try anyway, launch file explorer by right-clicking its exe, or a shortcut to it, and choose "run as admin").

Comment: Tryied, but got same error. Thank you, anyway